# Custom Log Method

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am attempting to implement a log system in cakePHP. I have a issue now were the methods contents in "write" are called twice. This causes an issue because it places 2 log entries of the same type in my system.

Databaselogger.php in the Lib/Engine/ directory:

```
App::uses('CakeLogInterface', 'Log');

class DatabaseLogger implements CakeLogInterface {


private $types = array();


public function __construct($options = array()) {
    // Allowed method calls
    $this->types = $options['types'];
}

public function write($type = NULL, $message = NULL) {

    // Only store to cache types that are permitted, other errors from cake are not reported
    if(!empty($this->types) && in_array($type, $this->types))
    {
        //make database entry here
    }
 } 
}
```

In my bootstrap.php :

```
App::uses('CakeLog', 'Log');
CakeLog::config('debug', array(
'engine' => 'FileLog',
'types' => array('notice', 'info', 'debug'),
'file' => 'debug',
));
CakeLog::config('error', array(
'engine' => 'FileLog',
'types' => array('warning', 'error', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency'),
'file' => 'error',
));

// Custom configuration
CakeLog::config('mytest', array(
  'engine' => 'DatabaseLogger',
'types' => array('mytest'),
'scope' => array(),
'file' => '',
));
```

This is how I call the method:

```
CakeLog::write('mytest', 'this message!');
```

Can anyone give some hints as to why this might be happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the namespace of the core files is

```
/Log/Engine/
```

I would assume that it should be

```
/Lib/Log/Engine/DatabaseLog.php (or Logger if you want to straggle from the core naming).
```

accordingly.

Proof you will get from the LogEngineCollection class, which contains:

```
App::uses($loggerName, $plugin . 'Log/Engine');
```

to include the engine of yours (hence the importance of the correct namespace).

Please take the time to look into the core code. Its open source after all :)

Comment: I actually took this example off the site itself and they use databaselogger.php as filename: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html

Comment: This also did not fix the problem I am having. Here is another odd note, when I call debug() it actually fixes the issue. But not calling it will cause the 2 logs to be form

Comment: I think there is a extra configuration setup you need that is not in the documentation. Possibly in your config bootstrap? There is not in the documentation however, your example does follow the cakephp book.

Comment: So did you correct the namespace and clear the cache? The latter is important for cake to find your class files via App::uses(). Also note that the logging stuff greatly improved over the 2.x versions. You might want to take a look at more recent releases here just to make sure its not that.

Comment: I corrected the namespace, and also cleared the cache. I am running ver. 2.2.5 at the moment. Do you suggest going to the 2.3 RC? It did not fix the issue.

Comment: If it is not working as documented, there might also be a bug in the core. It might be worth opening a ticket in that case.

Comment: I went ahead and opened a ticket here: http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/3539-databaselogger-example-called-twice